# Dependency Injection error , Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a .NET Core 6 MVC app using Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern to inject a repository into my controller, but it gives me an error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AqcCalama.Repositories.RepositoryPersonal' while attempting to activate 'AqcCalama.Controllers.PersonalController'.

Repository:

```
public class RepositoryPersonal
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext context;

        public RepositoryPersonal(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public List<Personal> GetPersonal()
        {
            return this.context.Personal.ToList();
        }

        public List<Personal> GetPersonal(string rut)
        {
            var consulta = from datos in this.context.Personal
                           where datos.Rut.Contains(rut)
                           select datos;
            return consulta.ToList();
        }
```

Controller:

```
public class PersonalController : Controller
    {
       
        private RepositoryPersonal repo;

        public PersonalController(RepositoryPersonal repo)
        {
            this.repo = repo;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult BuscadorPersonal()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult BuscadorPersonal(string rut)
        {
            List<Personal> per = this.repo.GetPersonal(rut);

            return View(per);
        }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

I am a bit lost, Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged SQL server since ita clearly not part of the problem.

Comment: It seems `RepositoryPersonal` is not registered in your servicecollection?

Comment: Yeah you need to show where you register your services.

Comment: I already updated the post with the services, I had read that and tried with "builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();" but i throw the same error

Comment: "builder.Services.AddTransient<RepositoryPersonal>();" If that is not the missing registration, please show all your service registrations.

Comment: yes that was the problem, now it works!  thank you I really appreciate it